# Pass variable arguments to newly created process

Tags: c, linux, process

In linux

I have temp.c file. In that i created new process and i need to pass all arguments to that

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( (cid1 = fork()) == 0 ) //child1
    {
        res = execv(proc1, &argv[1]); 
    }
}
```

Now i compile this and run as

```
./a.out "arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

Now i want to pass this arg1, arg2 and arg3 to new process created but inside that when i check argc it show me `2` instead of `4`

Why this mismatch happen and inside proc1 i have only 1 argument which value is `"arg1 arg2 arg3"` but here i want 3 argument so `argv[1] = arg1, argv[2]=arg2, argv[3]=arg3`

How to achive this?

Comment: It sounds like you may be invoking the first program incorrectly.  Did you try printing `argc` in the *first* program?  It should be 4, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's only 2, given what you're seeing.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I expected.  You're passing a single argument to the first program, which is `arg1 arg2 arg3`.  You're then passing that same argument to the second program unchanged.  Try removing the quotes from the command line.  That way they'll be passed as separate arguments.

Comment: Actulay  i need to must use that double quotes because in real case i have three process and 3 arguments grouped by double quotes...

Comment: Ok, well in that case you will have to parse the arguments yourself, inside your program.  You'll have to create a new `argv`, then copy the arguments individually and store the pointers in your new `argv`.

Answer (score 2):

Very useful example at
https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *const parmList[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "/u/userid/dirname", NULL};

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        perror("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("/bin/ls", parmList);
        printf("Return not expected. Must be an execv error.n");
    }
}
```

As you can see execv() accepts two arguments. The first is executable filename. The second is a pointer to an array of pointers to null-terminated character strings and NULL pointer is used to mark the end of the array.

Create new char* array, assign proc1 to first element (index 0) and required parameters to next elements.